# What does StreamConnectionNotifier do?

Tags: java, bluetooth

Does it run an internal thread that waits for incoming connections?

Comment: Why not hit google? `StreamConnectionNotifier source`

Comment: i already did, javadocs does not provide concrete explanation even other tutorials.